# how to get json array

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have this json taat I'm trying to convert to an aobject of type DataStreams  :

```
{
    "resultSize": "14",
    "requestedSize": "1000",
    "pageCursor": "c8bdb3d9-e-ccecb4a7",
    "items": [
{ "cstId": "5146"}]}
```

and I have this class :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

public class DataStreams {

    private String resultSize;
    private String requestedSize;
    private String pageCursor;
    private Item[] items;

    public String getResultSize() {
        return resultSize;
    }

    public void setResultSize(String resultSize) {
        this.resultSize = resultSize;
    }

    public String getRequestedSize() {
        return requestedSize;
    }

    public void setRequestedSize(String requestedSize) {
        this.requestedSize = requestedSize;
    }

    public String getPageCursor() {
        return pageCursor;
    }

    public void setPageCursor(String pageCursor) {
        this.pageCursor = pageCursor;
    }

    public Item[] getDataStreams() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setDataStreams(Item[] items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

}
```

then I do this in my application class :

```
DataStreams dataStreams = mapper.readValue(str, DataStreams.class);
```

but the items array is getting null.
How do I get the items array ?

Comment: ok I had to add @JsonProperty(value = "items")